# Get columns from joined tables as rows instead of adjacent columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have Three tables A_PRODUCT, A_MODEL, and A_AREA. These tables can be joined using PRODUCT_ID. I want to get an output such that a row from A_PRODUCT table is followed by rows from A_MODEL table followed by rows from A_AREA table for a product. Following is the SQL to create sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE A_PRODUCT
(
PRODUCT_ID NVARCHAR(30),
PODUCT_NAME NVARCHAR(30),
);

INSERT INTO A_PRODUCT (PRODUCT_ID, PODUCT_NAME)
VALUES ('P-1', 'LONG-SLEEVE LOGO JERSEY');

INSERT INTO A_PRODUCT (PRODUCT_ID, PODUCT_NAME)
VALUES ('P-2', 'GLASSES');


CREATE TABLE A_MODEL
(
MODEL_ID NVARCHAR(30),
MODEL_NAME NVARCHAR(30),
PRODUCT_ID NVARCHAR(30)
);

INSERT INTO A_MODEL (MODEL_ID, MODEL_NAME, PRODUCT_ID)
VALUES ('M-1', 'OLD JERSEY', 'P-1');

INSERT INTO A_MODEL (MODEL_ID, MODEL_NAME, PRODUCT_ID)
VALUES ('M-2', 'RAY-BAN', 'P-2');

INSERT INTO A_MODEL (MODEL_ID, MODEL_NAME, PRODUCT_ID)
VALUES ('M-3', 'ARMANI', 'P-2');

CREATE TABLE A_AREA
(
AREA_ID NVARCHAR(30),
AREA_NAME NVARCHAR(30),
PRODUCT_ID NVARCHAR(30)
);

INSERT INTO A_AREA (AREA_ID, AREA_NAME, PRODUCT_ID)
VALUES ('A-1', 'SOUTH', 'P-1');

INSERT INTO A_AREA (AREA_ID, AREA_NAME, PRODUCT_ID)
VALUES ('A-2', 'NORTH', 'P-1');

INSERT INTO A_AREA (AREA_ID, AREA_NAME, PRODUCT_ID)
VALUES ('A-3', 'EAST', 'P-1');

INSERT INTO A_AREA (AREA_ID, AREA_NAME, PRODUCT_ID)
VALUES ('A-4', 'WEST', 'P-1');

INSERT INTO A_AREA (AREA_ID, AREA_NAME, PRODUCT_ID)
VALUES ('A-5', 'SOUTH-WEST', 'P-2');
```

My expected output is:

```
|PRODUCT|P-1|LONG-SLEEVE LOGO JERSEY|
|MODEL|M-1|OLD JERSEY|
|AREA|A-1|SOUTH|
|AREA|A-2|NORTH|
|AREA|A-3|EAST|
|AREA|A-4|WEST|
|PRODUCT|P-2|GLASSES|
|MODEL|M-2|RAY-BAN|
|MODEL|M-3|ARMANI|
|AREA|A-5|SOUTH-WEST|
```

I have tried the following query but it is not giving me the desired output:

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
SELECT CONCAT('|PRODUCT|', P.PRODUCT_ID,'|',P.PODUCT_NAME,'|') AS Col1,
        CONCAT('|MODEL|', M.MODEL_ID,'|',M.MODEL_NAME,'|') AS COl2,
        CONCAT('|AREA|', A.AREA_ID,'|',A.AREA_NAME,'|') AS COl3      
    FROM A_PRODUCT P
    JOIN A_MODEL M
    ON P.PRODUCT_ID = M.PRODUCT_ID
    JOIN A_AREA A
    ON P.PRODUCT_ID = A.PRODUCT_ID
 )
 SELECT Result
 FROM CTE
 CROSS APPLY (VALUES (Col1,'Col1'),(Col2,'Col2'),(Col3,'Col3')
              )DT (Result,Names);
```

Comment: You want your rows returned in a certain order and yet your attempt to solve the problem doesn't use ORDER BY anywhere?  Why?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put the order by in the sample query, however, it won't give me the output I need as the rows I am getting are repetitive.

Comment: I think you want a UNION not a join!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really want to `JOIN` here. You need to use the `PRODUCT_ID` to sort the results of a `UNION`, and you need to force an additional sort based on the table that the information comes from.

Use a sub-query to get your data grouped the way you need it, with an outer `SELECT` to get the formatting you need for your export data.

```
SELECT
  CONCAT('|',d.DetailCol1,'|',d.DetailCol2,'|', d.DetailCol3,'|') AS DelimitedList
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      PRODUCT_ID AS SortCol1,
      1 AS SortCol2,
      'PRODUCT' AS DetailCol1,
      PRODUCT_ID AS DetailCol2,
      PRODUCT_NAME AS DetailCol3
    FROM @A_PRODUCT
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      PRODUCT_ID AS SortCol1,
      2 AS SortCol2,
      'MODEL' AS DetailCol1,
      MODEL_ID AS DetailCol2,
      MODEL_NAME AS DetailCol3
    FROM @A_MODEL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      PRODUCT_ID AS SortCol1,
      3 AS SortCol2,
      'AREA' AS DetailCol1,
      AREA_ID AS DetailCol2,
      AREA_NAME AS DetailCol3
    FROM @A_AREA
  ) AS d
ORDER BY 
  d.SortCol1,
  d.SortCol2;
```

```
+---------------------------------------+
|             DelimitedList             |
+---------------------------------------+
| |PRODUCT|P-1|LONG-SLEEVE LOGO JERSEY| |
| |MODEL|M-1|OLD JERSEY|                |
| |AREA|A-1|SOUTH|                      |
| |AREA|A-2|NORTH|                      |
| |AREA|A-3|EAST|                       |
| |AREA|A-4|WEST|                       |
| |PRODUCT|P-2|GLASSES|                 |
| |MODEL|M-2|RAY-BAN|                   |
| |MODEL|M-3|ARMANI|                    |
| |AREA|A-5|SOUTH-WEST|                 |
+---------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks Eric. This is giving the desired output in a sample data set. However, the actual scenario has many columns in Three tables and the number of columns do not match.Also, the JOIN is needed because the condition to select data is not on one column.

Comment: @OraAff Any time you post a question with sample data, and someone gives an answer that solves the problem with your sample data, and that solution doesn't work with your real data, it means you have done a bad job of posting your question.   You should probably mark this as the answer and post a new question with sample data that better represents all the complications of your actual data.

Comment: I was about to mark it as answered. Was just busy in fitting it in actual scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query to get your desired output-

```
SELECT '| PRODUCT | '+PRODUCT_ID+' | '+PODUCT_NAME +' |' FROM A_PRODUCT
UNION ALL
SELECT '| AREA | '+AREA_ID+' | '+AREA_NAME +' |' FROM A_AREA
UNION ALL
SELECT '| MODEL | '+MODEL_ID+' | '+MODEL_NAME +' |' FROM A_MODEL
```

Output is- (You can remove the spaces between values if required)

```
| PRODUCT | P-1 | LONG-SLEEVE LOGO JERSEY |
| PRODUCT | P-2 | GLASSES |
| AREA | A-1 | SOUTH |
| AREA | A-2 | NORTH |
| AREA | A-3 | EAST |
| AREA | A-4 | WEST |
| AREA | A-5 | SOUTH-WEST |
| MODEL | M-1 | OLD JERSEY |
| MODEL | M-2 | RAY-BAN |
| MODEL | M-3 | ARMANI |
```